# Swing JTextArea: Resize Dialog properly after automatic LineWrap

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

I hope I did not miss some duplicate question, I feel like this should be trivial!

Anyway, I have a `JTextArea` with text in it, with automatic line wraps:

```
public PleaseResize(){
    super();
    Container cp = this.getContentPane();

    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    area.setColumns(20);
    area.setLineWrap(true);
    area.setEditable(false);
    area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    area.setText("Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary, over many a quaint an curious volume of forgotten lore.");
    cp.add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    cp.add(new JButton("Hallo"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.pack();
}
```

I want the  text area to **resize** vertically to display the whole text... but it does not. It resizes happily if I choose the line breaks via pushing in `\n`, but with automatic wrapping, it just remains the size it is.

I somehow feel like I am missing something totally obvious...

**Edit:** for clarification:

On creation-time, I do not know how many lines the text will have (due to the automatic linebreaks happening). I am receiving Text via an XML-file, and it can vary between 0 and about 30 lines after wrapping. I have the vertical space to display everything, but I do not want to scroll or to have a huge, white area when there is no or only a little text to display.

---

**Edit 2:**

After rephrasing the question, they key to the problem I was facing was apparently not resizing the JTextArea, but making sure the dialog knows how big it is!

So, here is the link back to the solution I ended up using: [An automatic resizing Text above a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711140/swing-an-automatic-resizing-text-above-a-button)

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap `JTeatArea` with `JScrollPane` like next `new JScrollPane(area);` and then add `JScrollPane` to your `JFrame`.

Also you create `JTextArea` with empty constructor, use [`JTextArea(int rows, int cols)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea(int,%20int)) to specify count of rows and columns.

Comment: I may be missing a bit of information here, but while the scroll pane makes the area scrollable, it does not resize anything.

Comment: But on creation, I do not know the amount of lines yet... it changes from case to case. *goes edit her question*